# iPhone developer certificate request

Tags: iphone

I have a standard developer account($99). Can i generate the CSR in my friends mac or does the mac also need to be registered on my name ?

Comment: Surely this is a question Apple could answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to generate the CSR on the Mac that you will be using for development because the generation is going to create a private key specific to  you. You don't want that private key on someone else's computer or they can sign iPhone app binaries as you. Also, if you do this on your friend's computer you're going to have to manually export the keys and certificate to get them back on your own computer so you can code at home.

It really isn't worth the hassle. Just use your own machine to do this.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your main question: No, the Mac does not need to be registered in your name in order to work. The name it’s registered under isn't hard-coded into the certificate signing request in any way. That being said, however, I’d highly recommend using whatever Mac you’ll be using for development to create it, as the private key will be stored in your Keychain.

If, for some reason, you’re going to be using your friend’s Mac for development, then I would recommend creating a separate user accound on the Mac for development purposes. This would prevent your certificates from being installed on your friend’s Keychain. Alternatively, you could create a separate Keychain and put all of the iPhone development-specific certificates (and private keys) in there. That’s a little more work than creating another account, but might be the answer if, say, you need to develop while he’s logged in.

I don’t know your situation, so I don’t know the answer for you.